# "folderPattern" property not working correctly in checkstyle

Tags: java, spring-boot, checkstyle

I'm trying to integrate `checkstyle` so that I can define strict quality rules for my project. It's a spring-boot maven project. I have read the `checkstyle` documentation and this is how I configured it.

in **pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                    <version>8.17</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

in **checkstyle.xml**

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="RegexpOnFilename">
        <property name="folderPattern"
                  value="[\\/]src[\\/]main[\\/]resources[\\/]"/>
        <property name="match" value="false"/>
        <property name="fileExtensions" value="properties, xml"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

This is a minified version of `checkstyle.xml` and there are some other checks on it working without any issue.

I wanted to restrict the file types in the `/src/main/resources` directory to `properties` and `xml`.

To check whether it's working or not I have put `test.txt` file in to the `/src/main/resources` directory. But when I run `checkstyle:check` I'm getting following output rather than warning about `test.txt`.

```
[ERROR] src\main\resources\application.properties:[1] (regexp) RegexpOnFilename: File not match folder pattern '[\\/]src[\\/]main[\\/]resources[\\/]' and file pattern ''.
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the above configurations?